# How does the Solar Orbiter take images so close to the sun without melting its camera?

Tags: the-sun, camera, esa-solar-orbiter

The EUI on the NASA/ESA Solar Orbiter recently captured the closest ever images of the sun.  How is that made possible without destroying the imager?

Comment: it only removes its lens cover at night?

Comment: @uhoh night when imaging the sun seems unlikelly :) I have a feeling that the solution involves a full spectrum ND filter (or a filter letting only som wavelengths through) thus limiting heating of the electronics, combine with a reflextive lens cap to avoid heating the filter and you should be fine

Comment: @lijat - *I hear the Soviets have landed on the Sun* - *How did they do that without burning?* - *They landed at night!* (old, old joke)

Comment: by working within its design parameters

Comment: By Jove @uhoh, I...I think you've got it!

Comment: How do welders attach two pieces of metal without destroying their eyes? How can people watch solar eclipses without destroying their eyes? The answer is simple: Use a filter that block almost all of the incoming light.

Comment: perhaps your confusion over it being a NASA mission caused you to look in the wrong place for information. If you look at the ESA website, there'sa section dedicated to this mission. The information on [this page](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Solar_Orbiter/Technical_challenges_of_flying_too_close_to_the_Sun) may help you frame a more specific question

Comment: *ESA/NASA Mission. NASA here is only a passenger

Comment: There are a lot of details available here, enough for an answer. It's quite a "cool" system! (pun intended) https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/solar-orbiter-mission